# pyspark aggregation across columns via explode on columns?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks something like this:

```
data = [{'event_id':0, 'bid_0_a':1, 'bid_0_b':2, 'bid_1_a':1, 'bid_1_b':2},
        {'event_id':1, 'bid_0_a':1, 'bid_0_b':2, 'bid_1_a':1, 'bid_1_b':2}]
schema = T.StructType([T.StructField(nm, T.IntegerType(), True) 
                                     for nm in ['event_id', 'bid_0_a', 'bid_0_b', 'bid_1_a', 'bid_1_b']])
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(data, 
                            schema=schema)
```

that is

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|event_id|bid_0_a|bid_0_b|bid_1_a|bid_1_b|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       0|      1|      2|      1|      2|
|       1|      1|      2|      1|      2|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The real table has many bid's per event, with many more bid fields (more than a and b). Ultimately I want to categorize the bids and do some aggregation within each category. I think I first need to explode these columns, that is produce a table like:

```
+--------+---+--+--+
|event_id|bid| a| b|
+--------+---+--+--+
|  0     | 0 | 1| 2|
|  0     | 1 | 1| 2|
|  1     | 0 | 1| 2|
|  1     | 1 | 1| 2|
+--------+---+--+--+
```

I can imagine doing this by hand, but I'm wondering if there is a faster pyspark SQL way to do this? Maybe if I collected the bid_*_a columns into a map or array, I could use `explode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a kinda hacky solution using `create_map()`, `explode()`, and `pivot()`. I say kinda hacky because I rely on the `max()` function to aggregate when doing the pivot which should work as long as your column names are unique, but I feel like there should be a better way.

First create a map field from your columns. You will have to have a list of `bid_ids`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from operator import add
bid_ids = ['0', '1']

df4 = df3.withColumn(
    'map',
    f.create_map(
        *(reduce(
            add, 
            [[f.lit(b),
              f.create_map(f.lit('a'),
                           f.col('bid_%s_a'%b), 
                           f.lit('b'), 
                           f.col('bid_%s_b'%b))
             ] for b in bid_ids
            ]
        ))
    )
)
df4.select('event_id', 'map').show(truncate=False)
#+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
#|event_id|map                                                    |
#+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
#|0       |Map(0 -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2), 1 -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2))|
#|1       |Map(0 -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2), 1 -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2))|
#+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now call `explode()` twice (since the map is nested). If this is unclear, you can print out the intermediate step (omitted here).

```python
df4 = df4.select('event_id', f.explode('map'))\
    .select('event_id', f.col('key').alias('bid'), f.explode('value'))
df4.show(truncate=False)
#+--------+---+---+-----+
#|event_id|bid|key|value|
#+--------+---+---+-----+
#|0       |0  |a  |1    |
#|0       |0  |b  |2    |
#|0       |1  |a  |1    |
#|0       |1  |b  |2    |
#|1       |0  |a  |1    |
#|1       |0  |b  |2    |
#|1       |1  |a  |1    |
#|1       |1  |b  |2    |
#+--------+---+---+-----+
```

Once your data is in this format, you can call `groupBy()` and `pivot()`. You need an aggregate for the grouping, so I chose `max()` - it shouldn't matter since there should only be one value for each `(event_id, bid, key)` group.

```python
df4.groupBy('event_id', 'bid').pivot('key').max('value').show()
#+--------+---+---+---+
#|event_id|bid|  a|  b|
#+--------+---+---+---+
#|       1|  0|  1|  2|
#|       0|  1|  1|  2|
#|       0|  0|  1|  2|
#|       1|  1|  1|  2|
#+--------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: this is cool, still processing, but in answer, I think change `event_ids = ['0', '1']` to `bid_ids = ['0', '1']`, we just need to know the ids in the columns, not the potentially long list of ids for rows

Comment: You can use `.distinct()` and collect the unique ids.

Comment: That's awesome! get's me started with `map` and `pivot` thanks! To make the answer easier to follow, I'd change `event_ids` to something like `bid_ids` so as to not confuse it with the `event_id` column.  I see that we are making a map out of the columns `bid_0_a`, `bid_1_a`, that is why we need the list ['0', '1'], but that list is unrelated to the values in the `event_id` column, if there was a 3rd and 4th row in the dataframe with `event_id` 3 and 4, we wouldn't change any of the answer code?

Comment: @MrCartoonology sorry I thought the numbers corresponded to event ids, but I see that you meant bid_ids. I think the changes you made should be fine, but it's hard to know without seeing the data. Why don't you try it out and if it doesn't work edit your question or ask a new one. Good luck!